# writing subroutine to perform calculations on column

Tags: vba, excel

I have a column where some cells have values but most are blank.

What I want is to fill in the blanks by spreading the values. For example

> 1
>
> blank
>
> blank
>
> 3
>
> blank
>
> 5

would be changed to

> 1
>
> 1
>
> 1
>
> 1
>
> 2.5
>
> 2.5

Here's what I have so far:

```
Sub ()

Set z = range("numbers")


For n = 2 To z.Rows.Count

 x = z.Cells(n, 1)

If IsEmpty(x) Then
'do nothing

ElseIf x.End(xlUp).Row < z.Cells(1, 1).Row Then

  k = x / (x.Row - z.Cells(1, 1).Row + 1)

  z(Cells(1, 1), Cells(n, 1)).Offset(0, 5) = k

Else

 k = x / (x.Row - x.End(xlUp).Row + 1)


 z(Cells(x.End(xlUp), 1), Cells(n, 1)).Offset(0, 5) = k


End If



Next n
```

There are many problems with this code. There is an 'object required' error on the line of the for loop. Also endxlup would get me the final value rather than the first value I meet going up. I just wanted to show my efforts.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the rule is for setting the new cell values. What is the expected result for "spreading the values"?

Comment: see @cyril's explantion. 1 blank 5 blank 2 would evaluate 1,2.5,2.5,1,1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a wild guess, but you want go from bottom to top, and where the there are blank cells, evenly distribute the value of the last filled cell.

Going to take a stab with top-of-head code, untested:

```
dim i as long, lr as long, j as double, k as long
lr = cells(rows.count,1).end(xlup).row
j = 0 'value to be divided
k = 0 'number of cells to divide j across
for i = lr to 2 step -1 'assumes header in row 1
    if cells(i,1).value <> "" AND j <> 0 then
        if cells(i,1).value <> "" then j = cells(i,1).value
        if cells(i,1).value = "" then k = k+1
    else
        range(cells(i+1,1),cells(i+1+k,1)).value = j/k
        j = 0
        k = 0
    end if
next i
```

Comment: Yeah you are right about my intention. I see a problem in your first if because you haven't yet given j a value, or will it automatically evaluate to true in that case?

Comment: @Napolean j will start as 0 unless otherwise specified.  a proper code would say j = 0 BEFORE the loop starts.  Same thing for k.  In hindsight I should make both of those double, to ensure that the division produces a double value.... made both changes.

Comment: I am getting an overflow error on the range(cells(i+1,1),cells(i+1+k,1)).value = j/k. That's after you changed them to doubles so not sure what the problem is. Thanks

Comment: @Napolean looks like long/long, long/double, double/long, and double/double can each output a decimal value... will change code back for the counting section to be Long.  Overflow errors should be related to k = 0.